# Custom resource build steps in Eclipse managed project

Tags: c++, eclipse, build-process

I know this can be done using a makefile, alas I am not using a makefile, but rather Eclipse's "managed" C++ project. :( In any case, this is what I'm trying to accomplish:

I have a C++ project in Eclipse. I have a number of XML files in this project that specify information about source files that are auto-generated. When the XML files change, I would like a custom tool executed to convert them. The challenges are:

- These resources need to be built prior to compiling the project since they specify source and header files used in the compilation.
- They should be built only when the XML file is modified (header files are generated, so this is to avoid needless recompilation because a file timestamp changed).
- I'd like it included as part of the build process of this project, not a separate project.

I see moving to CMake in the future, but for the time being I am trying to make do.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a pre-build command in Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Build Steps. This command will be executed before each build.

I'm not aware of a built-in way to get the command to run only when the XML file is modified. If you want that, then instead of making the pre-build command the XML-converting command itself, you can make it a "make" command with a makefile with a single rule whose prerequisite is the XML file and which calls the XML-converting command.

Comment: This is what I originally thought of, and what I was hoping to avoid. :-/ Ah well.